# How to keep track of C++ objects

Tags: c++, list, object

I currently have an class grounds which is used to make objects for all the blocks that make up the ground for a game I am making. What is the best way to keep track of this somewhat large list of blocks? I know how to keep track of objects in python but I recently moved to C++ and I am unsure of how to go about setting up some sort of list that is easy to iterate through.

Comment: The default choice for containers is `std::vector`

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1fe2x6kt(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @AndyProwl Vectors can hold classes? so I would just type vector.pushback(Object_Name)?

Comment: @Roboinventor: No, vectors cannot hold classes. Vectors can hold objects, which are instances of classes. Perhaps you need to read some introductory book or tutorial on C++.

Comment: @AndyProwl So if I have a class called Class and I have a line of code saying Class Object_name then I cannot add that to a vector?

Comment: if `Object_name` is an object then yes, you can do `vector<Class> v; Class o; v.push_back(o);`

Comment: @AndyProwl Honestly... the whole time I have been trying to get vector to hold classes it never occurred to me that putting <Class> in the type def would fix the problems I was having... Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++, the standard library (also referred to as the standard template library) provides several *container classes* that store a collection of things. The "things" may be any data type, including fundamental and user-defined.

Which container to use depends on your needs. Here's an authoritative [article on it from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1fe2x6kt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Your best bet is to use either `vector` if you need the ability to refer to specific elements by their position in your container, or a `set` if the order of elements doesn't matter and you need to quickly be able to check whether a certain element is present.

Some examples:

```
vector<MyClass> mycontainer; // a vector that holds objects of type MyClass
MyClass myObj;
mycontainer.push_back(myObj);
cout << mycontainer[0] << endl; // equivalent to cout << myObj << endl;
```

Or using a set:

```
set<MyClass> mycontainer;
MyClass myObj;
mycontainer.insert(myObj);
if (mycontainer.find(myObj))
   cout << "Yep, myObj is in the set." << endl;
```

The reason there's no one ultimate container is that there are efficiency tradeoffs.  One container may be blazing-fast at identifying whether an element is present within it, while another is optimal for removing an arbitrary element, etc.

So your best bet is to consider what behaviors you want your container to support (and how efficiently!), and then to review the authoritative article I linked to earlier.